# Adding JPanel after removing it from JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm developing a Java Game. I'm stuck at a point,where I need to restart the whole game again after GameOver. Here is the skeleton of my program:

```
package projectflappy;

import java.awt.*;


public final class TheGame extends JFrame  implements MouseListener{
JPanel jp;
//declaration of the varibles

int x_width = 500;
int y_height = 500;

int count = 5 ;

Ellipse2D Ball;


int x_ball;
int y_ball;
int cord_xup1,cord_xdown1;
int cord_xup2,cord_xdown2;
int cord_xup3,cord_xdown3;
int cord_xup4,cord_xdown4;
int cord_xup5,cord_xdown5;

Boolean flag = true;

RoundRectangle2D up1,down1,up2,down2,up3,down3,up4,down4;

Font font = new Font("Matura MT Script Capitals",Font.ROMAN_BASELINE,40);
Font font1 = new Font("Matura MT Script Capitals",Font.ROMAN_BASELINE,20);
Font font3 = new Font("Matura MT Script Capitals",Font.ROMAN_BASELINE,20);

float das[] = {10.0f};
BasicStroke color = new BasicStroke(10,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL,20.0f,das,0.0f); 


GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(20, 0, 
Color.DARK_GRAY, 0, 10, Color.GRAY, true);

GradientPaint gp3 = new GradientPaint(30, 0, 
Color.BLACK, 0, 20, Color.GREEN, true);

Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

 //Getting the "background.jpg" image we have in the folder
Image background = kit.getImage("D:\\College\\Programs\\ProjectFLAPPY\\src\\projectflappy\\1.png");

JLabel a = new JLabel("Get Ready ! Click to Start.");
JLabel retry = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:\\College\\Programs\\ProjectFLAPPY\\src\\projectflappy\\unnamed.png"));

int score = 0;


    //constructor
    public TheGame() throws IOException 
    {

        super("Simple Drawing");

        setSize(x_width, y_height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        jp = new DrawingPanel();

        add(jp);

        addMouseListener(this);
    }

      ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           update();

           repaint();
        }

     };
    Timer t = new Timer(50,action);   


    public void init()
    {
        x_ball = 30;
        y_ball = 200;

        cord_xup1 = 175; cord_xdown1 = 175;
        cord_xup2 = 320; cord_xdown2 = 320;
        cord_xup3 = 460; cord_xdown3 = 460;
        cord_xup4 = 585; cord_xdown4 = 585;
        cord_xup5 = 700; cord_xdown5 = 700;

       retry.setVisible(false);
            retry.setBounds(175,260,46,46);
            a.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            a.setFont(font1);
            a.setVisible(true);
            a.setBounds(105,200,300,100);

  }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        a.setVisible(false);
        if( flag == false)
        {
            t.stop();

        }
        else
        {
            t.start();

        }
       y_ball = y_ball - 40;
        count--; 


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    // for drawing on the panel
    class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            setLayout(null);
            init();
            add(a);
            add(retry);

           // addMouseListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D)g;

            d.drawImage(background, -270,-30, this);
            Ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x_ball,y_ball,30,30);

            d.setColor(Color.green);
            d.setFont(font3);


            up1 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xup1,-5,30,175,20,20);
            down1 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xdown1,310,30,155,20,20);

            up2 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xup2,-5,30,200,20,20);
            down2 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xdown2,310,30,175,20,20);

            up3 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xup3,-5,30,230,20,20);
            down3 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xdown3,350,30,135,20,20);

            up4 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xup4,-5,30,115,20,20);
            down4 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(cord_xdown4,240,30,115,20,20);

            d.setPaint(gp2);
            d.setStroke(color);
            d.fill(up1);
            d.fill(down1);

            d.fill(up2);
            d.fill(down2);

            d.fill(up3);
            d.fill(down3);

            d.fill(up4);
            d.fill(down4);


            d.setPaint(gp3);
            d.setStroke(color);
            d.fill(Ball);
            d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            d.setFont(font1);
            d.drawString(""+score ,200,50);
            if( Ball.intersects(up1.getBounds()) || Ball.intersects(down1.getBounds()) || Ball.intersects(up2.getBounds()) || Ball.intersects(down2.getBounds()) || Ball.intersects(up3.getBounds()) || Ball.intersects(down3.getBounds()) || Ball.intersects(up4.getBounds()) || Ball.intersects(down4.getBounds()))
        {
            t.stop();
            flag = false;
            d.setColor(Color.red);
            d.setFont(font);
            d.drawString("Game Over : "+score ,100,250);
            retry.setVisible(true);
        }

            retry.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            init(); //reset properties
        }

        //...

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                 //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                   // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                 //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                   // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }
    });




        }

    }   
    public void update()
    {

        cord_xdown1 -= 5;
        cord_xup1 -= 5;

        cord_xdown2 -= 5;
        cord_xup2 -= 5;

        cord_xdown3 -= 5;
        cord_xup3 -= 5;

        cord_xdown4 -= 5;
        cord_xup4 -= 5;

        cord_xdown5 -= 5;
        cord_xup5 -= 5;

        if( cord_xup1 <=-20)
        {
            cord_xup1 = 500;
            cord_xdown1 = 500;
        }
        if( cord_xup2 <=-20)
        {
            cord_xup2 = 500;
            cord_xdown2 = 500;
        }
        if( cord_xup3 <=-20)
        {
            cord_xup3 = 500;
            cord_xdown3 = 500;
        }
        if( cord_xup4 <=-20)
        {
            cord_xup4 = 500;
            cord_xdown4 = 500;
        }
        if( cord_xup5 <=-20)
        {
            cord_xup5 = 500;
            cord_xdown5 = 500;
        }

        if(count >= 0)
        {
            y_ball = y_ball - 7;
            count--;

            if( y_ball == y_height)
            {
                t.stop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            y_ball = y_ball + 7;
            if( y_ball == y_height-70)
            {
                t.stop();
            }
        }

        if(cord_xdown1 == x_ball || cord_xdown2 == x_ball || cord_xdown3 == x_ball || cord_xdown4  == x_ball)
            {   
                score = score+1;

            }

    }



     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new TheGame();

    }

}
```

here `retry` is a `JLabel` in which I'm using a `MouseListener` to do things.
When I run,the `JPanel` gets completely removed from the `JFrame` but the new `JPanel` really doesn't seem to work. But only one component i.e, `a.setVisble(true)` works.

This is the frame when the Players gets out.

[image]

This Frames when the Player clicks on the retry button.

[image]

Comment: The paintCompenent() method is for painting only!!! Do not add a MouseListener to a component in the painting method. Every time the paintComponent() method is called you will be adding another listener to the component.

Comment: ok,I have removed the `MouseListener` from the `paintcomponent()` but still it doesn't work. I need the Old `JPanel` to be removed and a new `JPanel` should be placed in the `JFrame`.

Comment: Have you looked into `CardLayout`?

Comment: How is that related to repainting `JPanel`?

Comment: It allows you to switch between 2 panels. You said you wanted to remove the old panel and replace it with a new one; `CardLayout` allows you to do that

Comment: @VinceEmigh: that should probably be an answer since it is the best solution for swapping views. Either that or for the OP to figure out how to **"reset"** the state of his current GUI with swapping JPanels.

Comment: And one more thing both the `JPanel` are actually the same. When the user plays the game,he/she gets out and clicks the retry button and I want the whole `JPanel`to be drawn from first as it was earlier. Is it still possible using `CardLayout`? If so can you shown me a simple example? Thanks.

Comment: You still haven't fixed your non-compilable code, why?

Comment: I was bit busy in my College works. I am now working on the solution given by @Vince Emigh

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions; post any further questions on my post and I'll be glad to hell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your new panel is not showing is due to the component hierarchy being invalid. You attempt to revalidate, but you did it before adding the panel. You need to do it AFTER you add a component to an already visible container. Check out [`invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#invalidate()):

> This method is called automatically when any layout-related information changes (e.g. setting the bounds of the component, **or adding the component to a container**).

So you must validate after adding the component, not before. `revalidate()` invalidates then revalidates the component hierarchy.

**The proper way to handle this** would be to revert your game back to it's original form; just change everything back to how it was. No need to create a new panel.

You could create a method, `init()`, which sets your game to how it should be:

```
//Contains the properties that will change during gameplay
void init() {
    retry.setVisible(false);
    a.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    //...
}
```

Which you can then call when you create the board (in the constructor) and when you press retry (in the listener):

```
public DrawingPanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    setLayout(null);

    init(); //sets properties
    a.setFont(font1);
    a.setVisible(true);
    a.setBounds(105,200,300,100);
    add(a);

    retry.setBounds(175,260,46,46);
    retry.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            init(); //reset properties
        }

        //...
    });
    add(retry);            
}
```

You shouldn't add a listener to a component in your `update()` method, since `update()` will be called multiple times. Add it in your constructor.

If `retry` is a `JButton`, you should use an `ActionListener`. I wasn't sure, so I kept it as a mouse listener.

You should avoid using `null` layout ([absolute positioning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)). Layout Managers position and size components using specific calculations to ensure your resulting GUI looks the same on all platforms. There are a few uses where absolute positioning is a viable option, as mentioned in the tutorials, but it's always best to prefer a Layout Manager. IMO, null layout is bad practice, and the only reason one would use it is if they didn't understand layout managers, which is a problem in itself.

To learn more about layout managers, check out the [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) trail. Not only does the JDK come bundled with layouts, but you can also create your own or use a third party layout, like MigLayout

---

EDIT:

1. Post Swing code to the Event Dispatch Thread. Swing event handlers (painting, listeners) are executed on the Event Dispatch Thread. To ensure the Swing code you write is in sync with the EDT, post any Swing code that isn't already being executed on the EDT to the EDT by using `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait`.
2. Do not size your frame directly. Allow your frame to size based off the contents inside of it. Your DrawingPanel (the game canvas) should determine the size of the frame.
3. `TheGame` should not extend `JFrame`, since it's not a frame itself, rather than something contained within a frame. Having it extend `JPanel` would be a little easier on you (you won't be forced to create a new class to override the `paint` method). Although, **`TheGame` shouldn't extend anything, it should HAVE these things** (has-a relationship, not is-a). But since you're still a beginner, I don't wanna overwhelm you with a completely new design, so I considered `TheGame` to be the actual game canvas (where things will be draw; `TheGame` will extend `JPanel`), so you'll no longer need `DrawingBoard`.
4. As mentioned before, you should NOT add listeners (or do any task that is only needed once) in the paint method. Keep in mind that the paint method **is for painting**, not initializing or setting values. You should attempt to keep logic out of that method if possible.
5. Stay consistent. You use a `JLabel` for "*Click to start!*", yet you use `drawString` for "*Game Over*". Pick one or the other. This choice is really up to you. For this example, I chose to use `drawString`, since it's consistent with the rest of your rendering methods (how you paint the background, ball and obstacles)
6. **DO NOT CREATE NEW OBJECTS IN YOUR PAINT METHOD**. You're creating a ton of new objects every 50 milliseconds. This is NOT needed, and will harm performance ***critically***. When you use the `new` keyword, you create a new object. Instead of creating a new object to change it (or revert it back), just change it's state.
7. Take advantage of Object Orientation. It'll help keep you organized, and allow you to easily manage and scale up your application. Don't shove a bunch of variables into one class to represent a ton of different things (`cordx_up1`, `cordx_up2`... it's definitely not scalable).
8. Look into some of the `Adapter` classes like `MouseAdapter` and `KeyAdapter`; they allow you to handle events without needing to declare methods you might not use.
9. Use access modifiers. If you aren't familiar with them, get to know them. It makes managing code a lot easier if you know where it *can* be used ahead of time.
10. Your paths point to a specific drive with a specific name. This should not be the case, since not everyone uses that drive and/or folder name. Package your images with your project, then refer to them locally.

With that said, you have a lot of studying to do.

What I did was create a `Ball` class and an `Obstacle` class, to get a little more organized. `ball_x` and `ball_y` are now inside the `Ball` class, as well as the gradient for it. The objects we create from this class will now have these properties (states). I create 1 ball object for your game.

Instead of creating new variables for each pole (`cordx_up1`), the `Obstacle` class has 2 `RoundRectangle2D`,  `top` and `bottom`, which are the poles your ball is supposed to avoid. Each obstacle also has a gradient, which is used for both `top` and `bottom`. Now I can create 1 obstacle object for 2 aligned poles. You can change the starting `x` position of the obstacle (although I don't recommend allowing this; `x` should be set dynamically based on other obstacles' positions), as well as the size for `top` and `bottom`. I create 5 obstacle objects.

To keep your game labels organized (by color, message, location, font) while using `drawString` instead of `JLabel`, I created a `GameLabel` class.

I separated the main method into it's own class, named `Launcher`, which creates a `JFrame` and adds your game to it; all on the Event Dispatch Thread:

```
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.add(new TheGame());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Your `Game` class now extends `JPanel`, so you can override the `paint` method to render the game. I created 1 `Ball` and a `LinkedList` for your obstacles. I chose a `LinkedList` since inserting/removing from front/end is guaranteed constant time, meaning it'll take the same amount of time to remove/insert no matter how many obstacles are in the list. When the ball passes an obstacle, I remove it from the front of the list and add it to the back. The first obstacle in the list is always the next obstacle.

I saw how some Strings were being re-used, so I created final variables for them, which you can easily change. There's also the `currentlyPlaying` and `isAlive` booleans. `currentlyPlaying` is set to `true` when the user first clicks (to start the game), and set to `false` once the user has clicked to restart the game (after he lost).

`readyToJump` is the flag I use to forward mouse events to your `update()` method (technically your `updatePlayerPostion()` method, but it's still "centeralized" within your `update()` method). It's best to keep all your logic in one place. `readyToJump = true` would have been the only statement in your listener's method if you weren't relying on calling `timer.start()` in it. Since `update()` can't be called unless the timer has started, and `mouseEvent` starts the timer, we must still handle starting the game in your listener's method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public final class TheGame extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
    public static final int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500;

    private final String START_SCORE = "0", 
            START_MESSAGE = "Get Ready ! Click to Start.",
            BACKGROUND_URL = "/res/flappy.png";

    private boolean currentlyPlaying, readyToJump, isAlive = true;
    private int score;

    private Timer timer;
    private Image background;
    private GameLabel messageLabel, scoreLabel;
    private Collection<Obstacle> obstaclesInOrder;
    private LinkedList<Obstacle> obstacles;
    private Ball ball;

    public TheGame() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        addMouseListener(this);
        timer = new Timer(50, this);

        background = loadBackgroundImage();
        messageLabel = new GameLabel(START_MESSAGE, 150, 240);
        scoreLabel = new GameLabel(START_SCORE, 250, 60);

        obstacles = new LinkedList<>();
        obstacles.removeAll(obstacles);
        obstaclesInOrder = Arrays.asList(new Obstacle(175, 20, 45), new Obstacle(320), new Obstacle(460), new Obstacle(585), new Obstacle(700));
        obstacles.addAll(obstaclesInOrder);
        ball = new Ball(30, 100);
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!currentlyPlaying) {
            startGame();
        } else if (!isAlive) {
            reset();
        }

        readyToJump = true;
    }

    private void startGame() {
        currentlyPlaying = true;
        messageLabel.update("");
        timer.start();
    }

    private void endGame() {
        isAlive = false;
        scoreLabel.update("");
        messageLabel.update("Game Over. Your score was " + Integer.toString(score));
        timer.stop();
    }

    private void reset() {
        ball.reset();
        for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacles)
            obstacle.reset();

        messageLabel.update(START_MESSAGE, 150, 240);
        scoreLabel.update(START_SCORE, 250, 60);

        obstacles.removeAll(obstacles);
        obstacles.addAll(obstaclesInOrder);

        score = 0;
        isAlive = true;
        currentlyPlaying = false;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        update();
        repaint();
    }

    private void update() {
        if (isAlive) {
            updateBallPosition();
            updateObstaclePositions();

            if(ballOutOfBounds() || playerCollidedWithObstacle()) {
                endGame();
            } else if(ballPassedObstacle()) {
                addToScore();
                setupNextObstacle();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateBallPosition() {
        if (readyToJump) {
            readyToJump = false;
            ball.jump();
        } else {
            ball.fall();
        }
    }

    private void updateObstaclePositions() {
        for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacles) {
            if (obstacle.getX() <= -obstacle.getWidth()) {
                obstacle.moveToBack();
                continue;
            }

            obstacle.moveForward();
        }
    }

    private void addToScore() {
        scoreLabel.update(Integer.toString(++score));
    }

    private void setupNextObstacle() {
        obstacles.addLast(obstacles.removeFirst());
    }

    private boolean ballOutOfBounds() {
        return ball.getY() >= HEIGHT || ball.getY() <= 0;
    }

    private boolean ballAtObstacle() {
        Obstacle currentObstacle = obstacles.getFirst();
        return ball.getX() + ball.getWidth() >= currentObstacle.getX() && ball.getX() <= currentObstacle.getX() + currentObstacle.getWidth();
    }

    private boolean ballPassedObstacle() {
        Obstacle currentObstacle = obstacles.getFirst();

        return ball.getX() >= (currentObstacle.getX() + currentObstacle.getWidth());
    }

    private boolean playerCollidedWithObstacle() {
        boolean collided = false;

        if(ballAtObstacle()) {
                for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacles) {
                    RoundRectangle2D top = obstacle.getTop();
                    RoundRectangle2D bottom = obstacle.getBottom();

                    if (ball.intersects(top.getX(), top.getY(), top.getWidth(), top.getHeight()) || ball.intersects(bottom.getX(), bottom.getY(), bottom.getWidth(), bottom.getHeight())) {
                        collided = true;
                    }
                }
        }

        return collided;
    }

    private Image loadBackgroundImage() {
        Image background = null;
        URL backgroundPath = getClass().getResource(BACKGROUND_URL);

        if(backgroundPath == null) {
            background = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        } else {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(backgroundPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }

        return background;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        ball.paint(g);
        for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacles)
            obstacle.paint(g);

        scoreLabel.paint(g);
        messageLabel.paint(g);
    }

    //...
}
```

`loadBackgroundImage()` loads and returns an image. If a problem occurs (image probably isn't there), it returns a black image.

(Most of) The game logic is in the `update()` method. Although it should all be in there, we can't due to a design flaw (from you using `Timer` which manages `update()`, and you start the timer in a listener, therefore we needed some logic in the listener). Your logic should be easy to read, and every execution step should be monitored and set by highest priority to lowest.

First, I check to make sure the ball hasn't collided with anything or gone out of bounds. If one of those things occur, I end the game.

If not, I check to see if the player has passed an obstacle. If the player passes an obstacle, I add to the score:

```
private void update() {
    if (ballOutOfBounds() || playerCollidedWithObstacle()) {
        endGame();
    } else if (ballPassedObstacle()) {
        addToScore();
        setupNextObstacle();
    }


    updateBallPosition();
    updateObstaclePositions();
}
```

I then finally update the positions.

To avoid constantly comparing the player's position and the obstacle's position (to see if the player has passed it), I created a `boolean ballAtObstacle()` method, which checks if the player is at an obstacle. Only then do I compare positions:

```
private boolean playerCollidedWithObstacle() {
    boolean collided = false;

    if (ballAtObstacle()) {
        for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacles) {
            RoundRectangle2D top = obstacle.getTop();
            RoundRectangle2D bottom = obstacle.getBottom();

            if (ball.intersects(top.getX(), top.getY(), top.getWidth(), top.getHeight()) || ball.intersects(bottom.getX(), bottom.getY(), bottom.getWidth(), bottom.getHeight())) {
                collided = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return collided;
}
```

The `ball.intersects` method call is a bit messy. I did this so the shape didn't have to be specific, although you could declare the intersects method as `boolean intersects(Shape shape)`.

Finally, I gave it a more flappy bird feel by increasing the fall speed as you fall. When you jump again, it goes back to normal. The longer it takes you to jump, the faster you'll fall. If you don't like this feature, and don't know how to remove it, let me know and I'll show you how.

The other classes involved:

GameLabel.java

```
public class GameLabel {
    private String message;
    private Font font;
    private Color color;

    private int x, y;

    public GameLabel(String message, int x, int y, Color color, Font font) {
        update(message, x, y, color, font);
    }

    public GameLabel(String message, int x, int y) {
        this(message, x, y, Color.BLACK, new Font("Matura MT Script Capitals", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 20));
    }

    public GameLabel() {
        this("", 0, 0);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;
    }

    public final void update(String message, int x, int y, Color color, Font font) {
        this.message = message;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.font = font;
    }

    public void update(String message, int x, int y) {
        update(message, x, y, color, font);
    }

    public void update(String message) {
        update(message, x, y);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawString(message, x, y);
    }

    public Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Obstacle.java

```
public class Obstacle {
    public static final int DEFAULT_TOP_HEIGHT = 175;
    public static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_HEIGHT = 175;
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 30;
    public static final int DEFAULT_ARCH_WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int DEFAULT_ARCH_HEIGHT = 20;
    public static final int DEFAULT_TOP_INSET = -5;
    public static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_INSET = TheGame.HEIGHT + 5;

    private RoundRectangle2D top, bottom;
    private BasicStroke stroke;
    private GradientPaint gradient;
    private int initialX, x, width;

    public Obstacle(int x, int width, int topHeight, int bottomHeight) {
        this.x = initialX = x;
        this.width = width;

        top = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, DEFAULT_TOP_INSET, width, topHeight, DEFAULT_ARCH_WIDTH, DEFAULT_ARCH_HEIGHT);
        bottom = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, DEFAULT_BOTTOM_INSET-bottomHeight, width, bottomHeight, DEFAULT_ARCH_WIDTH, DEFAULT_ARCH_HEIGHT);

        stroke = new BasicStroke(10, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 20.0f, new float[] { 10.0f }, 0.0f);
        gradient = new GradientPaint(20, 0, Color.DARK_GRAY, 0, 10, Color.GRAY, true);
    }

    public Obstacle(int x, int topHeight, int bottomHeight) {
        this(x, DEFAULT_WIDTH, topHeight, bottomHeight);
    }

    public void reset() {
        x = initialX;
        top.setRoundRect(initialX, top.getY(), top.getWidth(), top.getHeight(), top.getArcWidth(), top.getArcHeight());
        bottom.setRoundRect(initialX, bottom.getY(), bottom.getWidth(), bottom.getHeight(), bottom.getArcWidth(), bottom.getArcHeight());
    }

    public Obstacle(int x, int width) {
        this(x, width, DEFAULT_TOP_HEIGHT, DEFAULT_BOTTOM_HEIGHT);
    }

    public Obstacle(int x) {
        this(x, DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    }

    public void moveToBack() {
        x = 600;
    }

    public void moveForward() {
        x -= 5;
        top.setRoundRect(x, top.getY(), top.getWidth(), top.getHeight(), top.getArcWidth(), top.getArcHeight());
        bottom.setRoundRect(x, bottom.getY(), bottom.getWidth(), bottom.getHeight(), bottom.getArcWidth(), bottom.getArcHeight());
    }

    public RoundRectangle2D getTop() {
        return top;
    }

    public RoundRectangle2D getBottom() {
        return bottom;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setPaint(gradient);
        g.setStroke(stroke);
        g.fill(top);
        g.fill(bottom);
    }
}
```

Ball.java

```
public class Ball {
    public static final int DEFAULT_DROP_SPEED = 7;

    private Ellipse2D ball;
    private GradientPaint gradient;
    private int initialY, x, y, width = 30, height = 30, dropSpeed = DEFAULT_DROP_SPEED;

    public Ball(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = initialY = y;
        width = height = 30;

        ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
        gradient = new GradientPaint(30, 0, Color.BLACK, 0, 20, Color.GREEN, true);
    }

    public void reset() {
        y = initialY;
        updateBall();
    }

    public void jump() {
        dropSpeed = DEFAULT_DROP_SPEED;
        y -= 40;
        updateBall();
    }

    public void fall() {
        y += dropSpeed++;
        updateBall();
    }

    private void updateBall() {
        ball.setFrame(x, y, width, height);
    }



    public boolean intersects(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        return ball.intersects(x, y, w, h);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return width;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setPaint(gradient);
        g.fill(ball);
    }

    public void moveForward() {
        x += 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! I tried up your solution. Only a part of the frame gets erased. I haven't got any solutions yet. Please check the full code and tell me where am I going wrong. Thanks. @Vince Emigh

Comment: @question I'm not sure what you mean by "only part of the frame gets erased"; mind editing a picture into your question showing the results? I see you updated your question with more code, I'll relate my answer to it

Comment: Hey there! I tried up your solution. Only some part of the frame gets erased. I haven't got any solutions yet. Please check the full code and tell me where am I going wrong. Typo erre. @Vince Emigh

Comment: Check out the Image of the game in my edited question. @Vince Emigh

Comment: @question Yes. Your structure is completely off, and will only complicate things as you scale up. Not to mention, your path names are dependent on the host machine. My answer will be edited shortly

Comment: Ya. Waiting for your answer. Thanks @Vince Emigh

Comment: Tell me how can I structurize my program in a better way. @Vince Emigh

Comment: Hey @Vince Emigh . I worked out through my code and found the answer. It was just a matter of `repaint()` to be called after the `init()`. Thanks for your time. I accept your answer as it was a main breakthrough for the code. Cheers!.

Comment: @question No problem. I'm sorry for the delay on the restructuring; not only is there quite a bit to be done, but my computer restarted an erased everything I had. I started working on another version; I'l quote you when I'm finished

Comment: Ya that's not a problem. I will still wait for your reply. I need to know how the program can be restructured in a good way

Comment: That was some knowledge gaining thing as I went through your codes. That's a neat one. I will start up a chat soon. I will let you know. Once again thanks! :)

Comment: @question No problem. I also forgot to mention that I switched to `ImageIO.read(URL)` for loading your background image. Toolkit loads the image *on a different (background) thread*. Because of this, the game was able to start before the image was finished loading. This gave the result of the background not showing up on the first frame (but it would pop up once you click to start). Just comment here and tag my name linking me to the chat, if you make one

Comment: Oh thanks for that info,I was wondering why this was happening. And yea definitely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67766/discussion-between-question-and-vince-emigh).

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67766/discussion-between-question-and-vince-emigh

Comment: I have created one. Hope to see you there.

Answer (score -3):

**Reinitialize all the components by adding the initialization code to one method(resetAll) and call that method when u want to reinitailize**

Below is an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

 public class ResetTest extends Frame{

Button b;
TextField tf;
Frame f;
Panel p;

public ResetTest(){
    f=this;  //intialize frame f to this to have access to our frame in event handler methods
    resetAll(); //first time call to resetAll will initialize all the parameters of the frame
    f.pack();
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });


    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,20,20));
    this.setVisible(true);

}

/**
This method will be called on click of button to 
reset all the parameters of the frame so that we
get fresh new frame, everything as it was before.
**/
public void resetAll(){
    b=new Button("Reset");
    p=new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,20,20));
    p.add(b);
    tf = new TextField("Edit And Reset");
    p.add(tf);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            remove(p); //remove the panel that contains all our components
            resetAll(); // reset all the components
            f.pack(); //refreshes the view of frame when everything is reset.
        }

    });

        add(p);     
    }
}

class NewClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ResetTest fReset = new ResetTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it won't work. All it does is change the object referenced by a variable, jp, and nothing else. -1. Changing a variable is not the same as changing the state of an object, which is what you need to do. Yes jp was added to the GUI, but changing the object jp refers to **after** the original jp object was added does nothing to the GUI whatsoever.

Comment: Then what am I suppose to do? Please help.

Comment: Try remove(jp); jp = new DrawingPanel(); add(jp);

Comment: If you need the whole code. I could give you for better understanding.

Comment: @question: You need to give DrawingPanel a `reset()` method that simply resets it to its original state, and in your JButton's ActionListener, simply call this method, that's it.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm asking,how do I reset the DrawingPanel ?

Comment: @question: we have no idea since you don't show us the key parts of the DrawingPanel code.